# Add the sequence number behind a data word

Tags: linux, sed, awk

My input

```
cat file 
ABC
ABC
DEF
DEF
ABC
GHI
GHI
DEF
```

The output that I want

```
ABC_1 
ABC_2
DEF_1
DEF_2
ABC_3
GHI_1
GHI_2
DEF_3
```

anybody can help,I google a lot ,but still cannot get how to get the output in unix .

Comment: The input cat file 
ABC
ABC
EFG
EFG

output I want 
ABC_1
ABC_2
EFG_1
EFG_2

all are in first column.

please help if you know ,thank you so much.

Comment: "I goofle a lot".  If you show what you have tried so far, however imperfect the results, you will get a friendlier reception here.

Comment: @cutrightjm seems this question is a substantial-enough variation from the former; this has unique numbering based on the actual text, not just the line number.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Add sequence number behind the data](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/309510/add-sequence-number-behind-the-data)

Comment: It's actually quite different from that other question even if it looks similar.

Comment: Is your file always sorted?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
$ awk '{print $1 "_" ++c[$1]}' file
ABC_1
ABC_2
DEF_1
DEF_2
ABC_3
GHI_1
GHI_2
DEF_3
```

The above uses a single awk command: `print $1 "_" ++c[$1]`.  This prints the first field, followed by `_`, followed by a count of the number of times that the first field has been seen so far.

Answer (score 2):

```
awk '$0=$0"_"++n[$0]' #comment
```