# Add sequence number behind the data

Tags: linux, sed, awk

My input for cat file

```
ABC   
DEF  
DEF   
ABC   
GHI   
GHI   
DEF
```

The output that I want is:

```
ABC_1 
DEF_2
DEF_3
ABC_4
GHI_5
GHI_6
DEF_7
```

I tried to use the loop to do it but it failed.

Comment: i want the output be in column form also

Comment: This is very similar to your previous question: http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/309491/add-the-sequence-number-behind-a-data-word

Answer (score 2):

```
$ awk '{print $1 "_" ++c}' file
ABC_1
DEF_2
DEF_3
ABC_4
GHI_5
GHI_6
DEF_7
```

Comment: thank you,now I only knew that one is store the value inside the array to execute the code,one is did not .

Answer (score 1):

```
awk '$0=$0"_"NR' # padding to meet minimum answer length
```